# Appearance of split lines in vim

Tags: c, vim

I would like to change the appearance of the vertical split division, which currently uses `|`. Is there a Vim setting, or can it be modified in the source code?  Please give me some tips.

[image]

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer, which may save you some downvotes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That settings is managed by the `fillchars` setting. To modify it to use a different character than `|`, use

```
" Set the vertical split character to +
:set fillchars+=vert:\+

" Set the vertical split character to  a space (there is a single space after '\ ')
:set fillchars+=vert:\
```

A single whitespace character for the vertical fillchar will make it so that your colorscheme's vertical split color is all you see.

#### Example using a single whitespace character as the second sample above.  The colorscheme background color shows through.

[image: This uses fillchars+=vert:\]

The width of the split line is dependent upon the current font size. It is one character width of the current fixed-width font.

Read the documentation on `fillchars` with

```
:help fillchars
```

Comment: @chm I don't think so. I believe it is the width of one character at your current font size.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to make it zero-width? I tried `set fillchars+=vert:` and `set fillchars+=vert:''` but no luck.

Comment: @Halst I don't know, maybe you could try a non-printable character instead of an empty string, though if it works that's quite a hack.